# HTML5 and offline mobile app

Tags: javascript, html, offlineapps

I am trying to provide pros and cons for HTML vs Native for an app that needs to work offline and also synchronize with the server every 15 mins or so and need some help with the ability/features of HTML5 solution:

1. From what I read LocalStorage is used to keep app data, synching etc.  but I also read that it is limited to 5MB.  My data could be as much as 300MB+.  I need verification of this limit
2. What library is used to populate/query LocalStorage?
3. Can an HTML5 app work offline fully with app data say 1GB using LocalStorage?

Thanks
H

Comment: How about you try and search your own questions and come to some conclusions? It should be possible to find out what the localStorage limit is, which native method or libs to use..

Comment: That is a rude response Ronni.  Did I not say that I read it is 5MB.  What is wrong with asking for confirmation from programmers who tried what I am about to do? and you say "native method"? I stated I am only investigating HTML5 solution!  If you have nothing to contribute please refrain from posting polluting comments

Comment: You could spend some time reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask notice the top headline "Search, and research"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to create a total offline app, you may need HTML5 ApplicationCache.
and if you want to store such a big data, maybe IndexedDB is more proper. it has a higher limit than localstorage. As far as I know, chrome has a limit 5MB for localstorage.

Comment: Thanks Freedom.  So the ApplicationCache uses the LocalStorage? I'll check IndexedDB.

Comment: @Hassan Hussein, ApplicationCache do not use LocalStorage. it has nothing to do with local storage. it can cache your pages,js,css and etc. it is defined to build offline app.

Answer (score 0):

1 It depends on the browser: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage#Storage_size

2 Just use code like:

```
localStorage.setItem("name", "Grim...");    
var username = localStorage.getItem("name");
```

You can find out more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

3 Maybe, but you'll have nowhere near 1GB to work with.